# how to populate array of object in coffee script using a loop

Tags: object

I have tried something like below in coffee script. I expect to populate and array of objects in 'objList'. it's running as as expected but in every iteration it overwrites all the array objects with the object received in current iteration. At the end of the loop I see all the array objects contain identical values and they correspond to the last element in stringarray.

Similar issue (related to array.push in coffee) has been reported before on stackoverflow but no satisfactory answer. Seems that a lot of people are seeing this problem. Is that a bug in coffee ?

```
strarray = [
        "2|file2",
        "1|file1",
        "0|file0",
        "3|file3",
        ]
obj = {color:"", file:"", dst:""}

objlist = for str in strarray
    array = str.split "|"
    obj.color = array[0]
    obj.file =  array[1]
    obj.dst  = "dst_" + obj.color
    console.log "{color:#{obj.color}, file:#{obj.file}, dst:#{obj.dst}"
    obj

for o in objlist
   console.log "objList ["
   console.log "{color:#{o.color}, file:#{o.file}, dst:#{o.dst},"
   console.log "]"
```

**Output:**

```
{color:2, file:file2, dst:dst_2
{color:1, file:file1, dst:dst_1
{color:0, file:file0, dst:dst_0
{color:3, file:file3, dst:dst_3

objList [
{color:3, file:file3, dst:dst_3,
]
objList [
{color:3, file:file3, dst:dst_3,
]
objList [
{color:3, file:file3, dst:dst_3,
]
objList [
{color:3, file:file3, dst:dst_3,
]
```

Can someone help in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer by myself.
all objlist elements are pointing to same obj (i.e. global object) (java script assigns by reference). Being new to Java/coffee script couldn't figure it out earlier.

By defining callback using a local obj variable withing the callback solves this issue.